# Why isn't my <h1> element showing?

Tags: css

I can't get the div with the id midCalendar to appear under the navigation menu. Any advice?

[Here](http://nicholasnicolo.com/calendar.html) is a link to the page I am talking about (although the same problem exists on the 'about me' tab, too). The page is extremely basic, which probably explains the noob question.

Comment: The `calendar` div is covering it.

Answer (score 0):

it is under the menu, you need to add padding top to the element to show try this:

```
<h1 style="padding-top: 100px;"> What am I doing this week?</h1>
```

Comment: You're a saint. I spent waaaay too much time on that yesterday.

Comment: Turns out that the problem was that my CSS wouldn't save on my site :/

Answer (score 0):

Your floatMenu is covering the div.To display the content in proper order in your HTML page include them into a table tag.

```html
<table>
<tr><td><div id="floatMenu"></div></td></tr>
<tr><td><div id="midCalendar"></div></td></tr>
<tr><td><div id="calendar"></div></td></tr>
</table>
```